# JQuery ui autocomplete not working with code igniter

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter

What I want to do is simple. I want the user to be able to put in a name and while inserting code igniter and JQuery ui looks up the database and starts posting recommendations .. So this is what I got so far with a bit of help from someone here on stackoverflow .. But its still not working at all.

The Jquery ui command

```
$("#update-text").autocomplete({source:"<?php echo site_url('userProfile/autocomplete');?>",dataType:"json", type:'POST'});
```

The form containing the text field in the php file

```
<div>
<form method="post" action="#" name="updatePlanForm">
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="update-text"></label>
<input type="text" id="update-text" name="updateText" value="What are you gonna do today?" onclick="removeText()"/>
</div>
<input type="button" class="small green button" value="Update Plan" name="updatePlanButton"/> <!-- once clicked JQuery sends a post to a controller send_plan and jquery will return the view -->
</form>
</div>
```

And finally I have a controller called userProfile and in it is a function called autocomplete

```
function autocomplete(){
    // this takes the text field and whatever the user writes it autocompletes it.
    //Every single place and event in the database should be displayed in this view in this format
    $req = $this->input->post('updateText');

  $arrResults = array('orange', 'apple', 'bannana');

  $array = array_filter($arrResults, 'mycallback');
  // filter the array containing search word using call back function

  function mycallback ($var) {
    global $req;

    if (preg_match('/^'.$req.'/', $var)) {
      return $var;
    }
  }

  $array1 = array();

  // filter null array
  foreach ($array as $arr => $val) {
    if(!empty($val)) {
      $array1[] = $val;
    }
  }

  //echo out the json encoded array
  echo json_encode($array1);




    }
```

The below code is added for @Andrew

```
<!-- styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/styles/general.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/styles/homepage.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/styles/css-buttons.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/styles/colors.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/plugin/jqui/css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css"/>


<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/scripts/removeTextClick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().''?>public/plugin/jqui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#abso").hide();
    $("#close").hide();

    $("#activity-feed").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/update_plan_feed');?>"); // if removed from userProfile then change here too
    $("#places-feed").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/suggested_places_feed');?>"); // if removed from userProfile then change here too
    $("#events-feed").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/suggested_events_feed');?>"); // if removed from userProfile then change here too




    $("#list-friends-feed-link").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/list_freinds');?>");
        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});

    }); //end click

    $("#list-pictures-feed-link").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/pic_feed');?>");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#list-groups-feed-link").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/list_groups');?>");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#notify").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/list_notifications');?>");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#close").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").slideUp("600",function(){});
        $("#close").slideUp("600",function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#broadcast-button").click(function(){

        $.post("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/send_broadcast'); ?>", $("#broadcast-form").serialize());

        });


    $("#update-text").autocomplete({source:"<?php echo site_url('userProfile/autocomplete');?>",dataType:"json", type:'POST'});


});


</script>
```

Comment: @Kay: If you look at the response from your controller action with Firebug, do you see the correct results?

Comment: @Andrew No man, I dont get anything excpet : "$("#update-text").autocomplete is not a function"

Comment: @Kay: In that case, are you making sure to include jQueryUI in a `script` tag in your document?

Comment: @Andrew Yes I am sure everything is included ..Is there anything in particular you would like to see? I edited the above post to include some code you might want to look at.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure that nested functions will work like this in classes 2) I'm 100% sure you can't use `array_filter` like this inside a class method, [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#78691).

Comment: @Kay: I noticed that you're using a custom version of jQueryUI. If you replace it with a reference to a CDN, such as http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI1811.ashx, does the error about autocomplete being undefined go away?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your configuration to setup the auto complete correctly:

```
$("#update-text").autocomplete("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/autocomplete');?>", {dataType:"json", type:'POST'});
```

EDIT: also, there isn't a **type** option on the current autocomplete plugin, not that I'm aware of, which causes issues with CI's url get filtering (as seen in the code at https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin/blob/master/jquery.autocomplete.js). You might need to modify the autocomplete code to let you use POST.

EDIT: you appear to be using the jQuery UI implementation, not the standalone. Looking at the options described at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ you can not pass in *dataType* and *type* options at the top level: those are unsupported. Also, you should change your codeigniter method to look like this (define *mycallback* before you use it):

```
  function autocomplete(){
    // this takes the text field and whatever the user writes it autocompletes it.
    //Every single place and event in the database should be displayed in this view in this format
    $req = $this->input->post('updateText');

  $arrResults = array('orange', 'apple', 'bannana');

  function mycallback ($var) {
    global $req;

    if (preg_match('/^'.$req.'/', $var)) {
      return $var;
    }
  }

  $array = array_filter($arrResults, 'mycallback');
  // filter the array containing search word using call back function

  $array1 = array();

  // filter null array
  foreach ($array as $arr => $val) {
    if(!empty($val)) {
      $array1[] = $val;
    }
  }

  //echo out the json encoded array
  echo json_encode($array1);
}
```

EDIT 2: to use POST for your requests, try this:

```
$("#update-text").autocomplete({ source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.post( "<?php echo site_url('userProfile/autocomplete');?", {
                        updateText: split(request.term).pop();
                    }, response );
                }});
```

Also, if you're using Firefox you can use Firebug to make sure requests are being fired.

Comment: @Femi Sorry, I got a bit confused. I didn't entirely  understand.

Comment: Ah, yes: you need to change the request parameter you're using in CodeIgniter to **term** instead of *updateText*. Also (unfortunately) it appears that jQuery UI's built-in remote datasource only uses GET, not POST (see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5353 with a longer discussion at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqueryui-autocomplete-post-option-for-remote-request): so you either need to implement your own custom remote datasource or make sure your CodeIgniter app accepts GET requests.

Comment: I've added a possible custom source that uses POST and calls CI: let me know if that works.

Comment: @Femi OK, so I tried it, Firebug is stuck I cant click on anything on that page and i get that autocomplete is not a function error. I think there is a problem with the brackets

Comment: Ah, I'd guess jquery UI isn't loading properly.

Comment: @Femi .. So what now? If its a JQuery thing then I need to check it somewhere there. This is a really important function in this site we are making

Comment: Well, you're probably best served figuring out what errors Firebug can give you.